# Вычисление строково-логических выражений

Tags: логика, парсер, c++

Хочу написать программу для вычисления логических выражений 
Например: 
Ввод: *1&1&(0|0)*
Вывод: *0*

Но у меня очень плохая ошибка :) Stackoverflow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string str;
int i = 0;

int number(){
    int res = 0;

    for (;;){
        if(i>=str.length()) return res;
        char c = str[i];

        if (c == '0'){
            res = 0;
            i++;
        }else if(c == '1'){
            res = 1;
            i++;
        }else return res;
    }
}

int expr(){
    int x = skobki();

    for (;;){
        if(i>=str.length()) return x;
        char c = str[i];

        switch (c){
        case '&':
            i++;
            x &= skobki();
      break;
        case '|':
            i++;
            x |= skobki();
      break;
        default:
            return x;
        }
    }
}

int skobki(){
    char c = str[i];

    if (c == '('){
        int x = expr();
        return x;
  }else 
      return number();
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    cout << "Введите лог. выражение: ";
    cin>>str;
    int res = expr();
    cout << "Результат: " << res << endl;
    cin>>res; //задержка
}
```

Может есть другие предложения, по решению данной проблемы
Линки, листинги, статьи - буду благодарен :)

Comment: Сходу видно, `expr()` сразу вызывает `skobki()`, а она для '(' `expr()`, а `i` при этом не меняется. 

Вот тут рекурсия зацикливается. Где и как увеличивать `i` думайте сами.

Comment: @avp, оу глупая ошибка. Спасибо!